# Spring Data Rest persistence annotations

Tags: java, jpa

I'm learning Spring-Data-REST and have run into a snag involving my annotations.  Currently I have the following schema:

```
create table user
(
    ID int NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PASS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    primary key (ID)
);

create table recipe
(
    ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    NAME varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    USER_ID int NOT NULL,
    primary key (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES user(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

create table ingredient
(
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    NAME varchar(60) not null,
    primary key(ID)
);

create table ingredientsList 
(
    ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    NAME varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    RECIPE_ID int not null,
    INGREDIENT_ID int not null,
    QUANTITY int not null,
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (RECIPE_ID) REFERENCES recipe(ID) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (INGREDIENT_ID) references ingredient(ID) on delete cascade
);

create table direction
(
    ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    NAME varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    RECIPE_ID int not null,
    STEP int not null,
    DESCRIPTION varchar(256),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (RECIPE_ID) REFERENCES recipe(ID) on delete cascade
);
```

I've got every table represented in my Spring Data REST API except for one, which is the ingredientsList table.  Here is my current implementation that is not working correctly when I run .\mvn clean install:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class IngredientsList extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private Recipe recipe;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredientsList", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long quantity;

    public Recipe getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    public Set<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(Set<Ingredient> ingredients){
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public Long getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Long quantity){
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Long getResourceId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Compares Ingredients
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return Objects.equals(id, ((Ingredient) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

}
```

Here is my Ingredient class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Ingredient extends AbstractEntity {

    public Long getResourceId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is my AbstractEntity class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

As it stands, I'm running into an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown
>   target entity property:
>   com.mjf.beerstein.entities.Ingredient.ingredientsList in
>   com.mjf.beerstein.entities.IngredientsList.ingredients

I'm certain my issue is my annotations, though I'm not sure how to fix them.  A piece of example data for the ingredientsList table would be as follows, where the IDs for Recipe and Ingredient are tied together and given a quantity:

```
ID Name     Recipe_ID  Ingredient_ID  Quantity
1  "n/a"    1          1              2
2  "n/a"    1          2              1
3  "n/a"    1          5              1
4  "n/a"    2          1              2
```

Here are the dependencies of my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you post your Ingredient class?

Comment: Done.  I added my AbstractEntity class as well.

Comment: when you use mappedBy = "ingredientsList", you saying to jpa that you have in Ingredient entity a ingredientsList attribute

Comment: This got rid of my original error, but it presented me with a new error when I try to hit that endpoint in my API:

could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Table 'beerstein.ingredients_list' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Join_Table

I completely did away with my IngredientsList entity and repository, and instead added the following to my Recipe.java Entity:

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable
    (
        name="ingredientslist",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="recipe_id", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id", referencedColumnName="ID", unique=true)}
    )
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients;
```

I also removed the ID and Name attributes from the ingredientslist table, as they were unnecessary.  This allows me to traverse the ingredientslist table to pull each ingredient for a recipe via the API.  When querying the recipe endpoint, i get this:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "recipes": [
            {
                "name": "Coffee Stout",
                "resourceId": 1,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes/1"
                    },
                    "recipe": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes/1"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes/1/user"
                    },
                    "ingredients": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes/1/ingredients"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/recipes"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 5,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

And when following the endpoint to the ingredients conclusion, i receive this:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "name": "wheat grain",
                "resourceId": 1,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/ingredients/1"
                    },
                    "ingredient": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/ingredients/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/recipes/1/ingredients"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to all for helping me debug!

Comment: If this is working for you, that's great. There are a couple of things, though - Recipe -> Ingredient as you have it above is really a ManyToMany. You also don't have a quantity of an ingredient in a recipe any more.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@OneToMany` annotation on the `IngredientsList` class implies that there should be an `ingredientsList` field in the `Ingredient` class, which there is not. In your schema, you have an `INGREDIENT_ID` field in your `ingredientsList` table, implying that an `IngredientsList` can only have one `Ingredient`.

I think you meant for the `IngredientsList` to have many `Ingredient` children, which means the `ingredient` table should have an `INGREDIENT_LIST_ID` field as a foreign key to the `ingredientsList` table, and the `Ingredients` class should have an `ingredientsList` field. The `INGREDIENT_ID` field should be dropped from the `ingredientsList` table.

---

If an `IngredientsList` should only have one `Ingredient`, then change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredientsList", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Ingredient> ingredients;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn("ingredient_id")
private Ingredient ingredient
```

add `cascade` and `orphanRemoval` as required. A `@ManyToOne` should fetch the joined data eagerly by default.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your design - based on the example data you provided, maybe you meant for each `IngredientList` to have only one `Ingredient`?

Comment: I'm worried that if I place INGREDIENT_LIST_ID on my ingredient table that i'll end up with redundant ingredients in that table, one instance for each time that ingredient appears on any list.  I'm trying to keep that relationship in the ingredientsList to eliminate that redundancy.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, so you want a `@OneToOne` instead of `@OneToMany` on `IngredientsList.ingredients`. Or a `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: I think my language is wrong.  I'm misunderstanding why it wouldn't be a @OneToMany relationship.  One ingredient list has many ingredients.  Do I have it backwards?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "one ingredient list has many ingredients". In your example data, you have ingredient list 1 has ingredient 1 and ingredient list 4 has ingredient 1. This means the relationship from `IngredientList` to `Ingredient` is many-to-one (many ingredient lists can have the same ingredient). Going the other way, one ingredient can be in many ingredient lists. So if you had a mapping on `Ingredient`, that would be `@OneToMany`, but going from `IngredientList` to `Ingredient`, it's `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Ah, I understand where the confusion is.  In this instance, an ingredient list is denoted by the recipe id.  Each recipe is essentially one list of ingredients.  I think I shouldn't have placed an id or name in this table as they're not really needed.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yes. `name` seems like it should be in `Ingredient`. If you remove the `id` from `IngredientsList`, then it's no longer an Entity, and could be converted to an `@Embeddable`, in an `@ElementCollection` on the `Recipe`.